# In a food composition database, how would you model a food's relationship with its nutrients?

Tags: database-design

I am building a Web application that shows the nutrient content of foods.

My data is currently stored in a `foods` table, where each nutrient is a column with a numeric value, e.g.:

| name | sodium | potassium | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bread, ciabatta | 350 | 152 |  |

However, this means I have to hardcode the nutrient name (e.g. "Sodium") and the unit (e.g. "mg") in my application. I would prefer this came from the database too, in what I imagine would be some kind of fixed definition table, e.g.:

| id | name | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "NA" | "Sodium" | "mg" |
| "K" | "Potassium" | "mg" |

I wanted to see if there was a better way of referencing the definitions, than by creating more columns in the `foods` table, e.g.:

| ... | sodium | sodium_value | salt | salt_value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | "NA" | 350 | "SALT" | 152 |  |

So I naively implemented the following:

[image: A database diagram]

However I notice a lot of repetition in the `food_nutrients` table i.e. ~30 rows of nutrient values for each food and wondered if a) this is a problem in a database with a growing amount of foods, and b) if there is a more appropriate model that someone with more experience could suggest?

Comment: What you describe is an EAV design, generally considered to be a bad idea, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/14868997 et al. What is stopping you having all those columns? Is there a high likelihood of very many columns, with different rows having very different composition of non-null columns? (It would seem not to me, as a nutrition label doesn't change that much between foods) If there really is many different possible combinations of data per row, then you may want to look at a single XML or JSON or BSON column (depending on which DBMS)

Comment: Thanks for your input, and sharing that resource, @Charlieface. There is a high likelihood of up to 75% of columns being null when new foods are added by users. I'm using Postgres and considered JSONB, but came to the conclusion this might limit my ability to select foods that are high in x, y, z nutrients - keen to hear your thoughts.

Comment: You can query and index JSON/JSONB columns in Postgres, so it's not such a bad idea. I would stick to JSONB as it's more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design with the `food_nutrients` table is perfect, don't change it.

Of course there will be duplicates, since many recipes will require a tablespoon of salt. That is a repetition that is inherent in your data and nothing bad – after all, you are modeling a repetitive reality. I believe that any attempt to get rid of duplication would complicate and worsen the data model.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz. If you don't mind me asking, what's your take on Charlieface's comments above?

Comment: I agree with his dislike for "EAV design", but that's not what you are planning to do; he must have misinterpreted the question. But I strongly disagree with storing references to another table in a composite object like a JSON - that [will lead to suffering](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/json-postgresql-how-to-use-it-right/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. P.S. Nice article!

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, I'm revisiting this design two years later and wondered I might be able to get your take on it? I've created a new question at the following URL: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333251/how-can-i-simplify-our-process-of-importing-only-changed-data.